Azure bandwidth cost for AKS drill down
I'm using AKS service in Azure, and looking at the costs I can see that a big chunk is consumed by bandwidth.
According to pricing calculator, ingress traffic directed toward Azure data centers is not subject to charges, therefore there are no associated costs concerning inbound traffic. 
I would like to have a more detailed view concerning the outbound traffic, until now I've taken a look at the Cost Analysis, but it seems that this is the granularity offered by it:

Any suggestions or insights?
Update @francesco cost analysis by service:


I think it might be much worst than you think.
We use AKS and these is my breakdown:

As you can see the Bandwidth is at the positoni number 9, much lower than many other things that cost x10 time more.
Do this:

Go into the Cost Analysis
Add Filter > Resource Group Name, and set here one or more Resource Groups in which you have AKS
Group by > Service Name

You will be surprised

Did just that, to be quite honest I was expecting the same but funny enough it seems that bandwidth is no 1 consumer. I've updated the question with the chart

I think it's about your application and what it does

I've leveraged Prometheus and used container_network_transmit_bytes_total metric to find the application that generated the traffic, also looking in Azure at the outgoing traffic (number of billable bytes out on all network interfaces by the Kubernetes virtual machine scale set) helped
